# Can't get wifi thermostat to work with gas boiler

Tags: thermostat, thermostat-c-wire, boiler, wifi

I bought a Sensi WiFi thermostat and I have been trying to install it. I can't quite figure out how this wiring should work. Here is a link to pictures of the boiler and the current thermostat. The red wire from the thermostat is connected to Y on the boiler terminal and the black wire connected to G. The white wire wasn't connected to anything so I tried connecting it to the C terminal to be a common wire. When going through the sensi installation guide it says that having a Y and G isn't a valid configuration. I don't see what is wrong with the setup. Can anybody help me correct this and get my thermostat working please?

Thermostat:
[image]

Boiler plate:
[image]

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/2stcyom link didn't stay in post for pictures, here it is

Comment: Can you post pictures of the nameplate and/or wiring diagram for your boiler please?

Comment: I hope this is what you mean https://m.imgur.com/baGUeyY  I'll  try to see if the wiring diagram is around somewhere. I just recently bought the house.

Comment: How many wires are in the existing thermostat cable, and is adding an additional 24VAC transformer + relay to the system an option?

Comment: Also, I take it your system is heating-only, correct?

Comment: Yes, it is heat only. There are 3 wires in the thermostat cable, the red, the white, and the black one. The red and black are connected at the boiler, the white isn't connected to anything. I wouldn't know anything about adding a 24VAC transformer and relay, if it's something that I could do myself, I could try.

Comment: The [control supplement](https://www.weil-mclain.com/sites/default/files/field-file/he-vhe-series-3-hsi-supplement_1.pdf) for your boiler, BTW -- linking this here for reference purposes.

Comment: BTW: if you're wondering why this isn't trivial, it's because the terminal normally used to provide 24VAC to the thermostat *stops* providing 24VAC to the 'stat when the burner stops firing, but before the pressure switch returns to its rest position.  This is fine for an analog t-stat, but would addle the brain of a smart one...

Comment: Okay, I think I see. So I need the additional 24VAC and relay for the c-wire? I not sure where to connect the wires on for the thermostat as well. I tried plugging them into R and G but the heat just consistently ran. And they appear to be on Y and G but trying that didn't work at all. Is it all just because I need that additional 24VAC?

Comment: It's neither of those -- the nomenclature on your boiler is rather nonstandard as well.  I need to talk to Weil-McLain tech support about the role that 24VAC dropout to the 'stat plays in the safety of the overall system, BTW, so it'll be a little bit before I can give a confident answer here.  In the meantime, though, please don't try random wires trying to get this to work....

Comment: Okay, I really appreciate all of your help. I just have the original thermostat still hooked up until I understand how to properly install the Sensi WiFi one.

Answer (score 2):

### You'll need a relay here

Your boiler, in addition to using nonstandard wire nomenclature, does not provide 24VAC power directly to the thermostat.  Instead, power to the thermostat circuit is supplied through the parallel combination of a control relay contact and the NC contact on the combustion pressure switch.  This means that when the thermostat stops calling for heat, 24VAC power to the 'stat is cut off until the pressure switch opens again.  This is fine for a mechanical thermostat like your current one, but a smart thermostat like the Sensi will get its brain turned to mush every time the boiler kills its power supply.

As a result of this infelicity of the HE Series III's control wiring scheme, you will need to fit a HVAC relay (often sold as a "fan relay" -- these will have a 24VAC coil and at least one NO contact on them) to your system to isolate the thermostat from the boiler's thermostat circuit.  The relay needs to be mounted in a suitable place in the boiler's wiring compartment, and is wired as follows, although you may need to crimp 1/4" female quick-connect/tab terminals onto the wires going to the relay to make the connections to it, depending on the relay you get of course:

- One relay *coil* terminal to the *white* wire from the thermostat cable
- The other relay *coil* terminal connected to a jumper nutted with the *black* wire from the thermostat cable and another jumper that goes off to the C terminal on your boiler
- One relay *contact* terminal (the COM terminal) jumpered to the Y terminal on your boiler
- The other relay *contact* terminal (the NO terminal) jumpered to the G terminal on your boiler
- And the *red* wire from the thermostat cable connected through to the R terminal on your boiler

Once this is done, you can then wire the Sensi as follows:

- White thermostat wire goes to W (to drive the relay coil with 24VAC on a call for heat)
- Red thermostat wire goes to R (to power the thermostat, using the boiler's transformer)
- Black thermostat wire goes to C (to provide the 24VAC return for thermostat power)

This way, the Sensi will operate the new relay on a call for heat, closing the thermostat circuit as a result, while having constant 24VAC power available to it, so it doesn't lose its brain every time it stops calling for heat.

Comment: I tried wiring everything up exactly as you wrote and it ended up frying the transformer

Comment: @DannyWilloughby -- strange...what did you use for a relay?

Comment: This one. https://www.supplyhouse.com/White-Rodgers-90-380-Fan-Relay-Type-184-24-VAC-Coil-50-60-Hz-SPNO-SPNC-Coil-Data-77-Ohms-DC-Resistance-125-mA?gclid=Cj0KCQiAk-7jBRD9ARIsAEy8mh7Hz0Q1bETElI0ZGSQc32mMHRqnbeXWsTxs8oOU78n8YKhQQ2HXizwaAsjXEALw_wcB

Comment: ....very strange indeed, this one's got me baffled, that relay should work.

Comment: @DannyWilloughby The only thing I can think of is that the Sensi is pulling too much power from the boiler -- in which case, you'll need to use the isolation relay, but with a separate transformer...